# CSS background property applied to HTML Input element within Table cell

Tags: html, css, background, html-table, html-input

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oe2ofup6/)

When you hover over an input field in the table, the entire cell turns grey except for a few pixels at the top. Why is that? I've tried setting everything I can think of (margin, padding, box-shadow, etc) to `0` or `none`, but to no avail.

Comment: `td { line-height: 100% }`. the size of the text in the input doesn't match the height of the table cell. setting `line-height: 100%` on the cell itself fixes that

Comment: @MarcB: best solution! Voting up. Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've not defined a height on the Input field, therefore it's smaller than the containing td

```
td input {
     height:20px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oe2ofup6/2/

Answer (score 1):

Consider changing your CSS to check for `td:hover` instead of `input:hover`.

Instead of:

```
td input:hover {
    background-color: #8d8d8d;
}

td input {
    width: 100%;
    border: 0;
}
```

try:

```
td input {
    width: 100%;
    border: 0;
}

td:hover, td:hover input {
    background-color: #8d8d8d;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zg49zejo/1/)